# specutils fit_generic_continuum giving TypeError when used on Spectrum1D

Tags: python, typeerror, astropy

I'm trying to fit a generic continuum to my spectrum to normalize it (I realize this isn't a very good method for complicated spectra, but can't seem to find a good continuum normalization routine for spectra in Python, so if you know of one please let me know!!).

Here's my code. w is the wavelength array and f is the flux array (which are just imported data):

```
from astropy.modeling import models
from astropy import units as u

from specutils import Spectrum1D, SpectralRegion
from specutils.fitting import fit_generic_continuum

spectrum = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=w*u.Angstrom, flux=f*u.Jy)

g1_fit = fit_generic_continuum(spectrum)

f_continuum_fitted = g1_fit(w*u.Angstrom)

spec_normalized = spectrum / f_continuum_fitted
```

Now, this worked BEFORE I recently updated astropy and specutils. But now, I suddenly get a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` at the `g1_fit = fit_generic_continuum(spectrum)` line. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling specutils, and still get the same error. I've also tried renaming spectrum to something else.

Was there something new in the update with `fit_generic_continuum`, or am I missing something?

Thanks so much in advance!!

I'm using astropy version 4.0.1 and specutils version 0.6

Full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b277c08fb857> in <module>
     14 spectrum = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=w*u.Angstrom, flux=f*u.Jy)
     15 
---> 16 g1_fit = fit_generic_continuum(spectrum)
     17 
     18 f_continuum_fitted = g1_fit(w*u.Angstrom)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/specutils/fitting/continuum.py in fit_generic_continuum(spectrum, median_window, model, fitter, exclude_regions, weights)
     55     #
     56 
---> 57     return fit_continuum(spectrum_smoothed, model, fitter, exclude_regions, weights)
     58 
     59 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/specutils/fitting/continuum.py in fit_continuum(spectrum, model, fitter, exclude_regions, window, weights)
     95     #
     96 
---> 97     continuum_spectrum = fit_lines(spectrum, model, fitter, exclude_regions, weights)
     98 
     99     return continuum_spectrum

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/specutils/fitting/fitmodels.py in fit_lines(spectrum, model, fitter, exclude_regions, weights, window, **kwargs)
    358         fit_model = _fit_lines(spectrum, model_guess, fitter,
    359                                exclude_regions, weights, model_window,
--> 360                                ignore_units, **kwargs)
    361 
    362         fitted_models.append(fit_model)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/specutils/fitting/fitmodels.py in _fit_lines(spectrum, model, fitter, exclude_regions, weights, window, ignore_units, **kwargs)
    474 
    475     model_unitless, dispersion_unitless, flux_unitless = \
--> 476         _strip_units_from_model(model, spectrum, convert=not ignore_units)
    477 
    478     #

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/specutils/fitting/fitmodels.py in _strip_units_from_model(model_in, spectrum, convert)
    602     #
    603 
--> 604     compound_model = model_in.n_submodels() > 1
    605 
    606     if not compound_model:

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback that preceded the exception message, as that provides valuable additional context to what's causing the error, as well as your astropy and specutils versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a solution to your code issue, but since you asked for recommendations for normalization routines I can help you with that. I use the Python based linetools package. There is a routine within it "lt_continuumfit" which does a beautiful job normalizing continuum. It's all I use for normalizing now. It's very easy to install and use and has many other functions as well (rebin, velocity plots, splicing, etc). https://linetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/